# Increase in Dirty Cache in Mongodb when we added a new replica set member

Tags: replication, mongodb

Mongo Version: `3.6`

Database Engine: `Wiredtiger`

Old Cluster:

- 1 Primary
- 1 Secondary
- 1 Arbiter

We wanted to replace the secondary with a new machine, so we added a new Replica set. Due to which the percentage of Dirty Cache started increasing.

We did not find anything in the Logs. Can anyone help us figuring out what we did wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "we added a new Replica set"? I would add the new node to the replica set, wait for synchronization and then remove the old member. NB, MongoDB version 3.6 is [End-Of-Life](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy/lifecycles) since April 2021

Comment: We added a new member (node) to the existing Replicaset. We did the synchronisation from existing secondary and not from primary directly.